# Trying to achieve predictable search results from Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

Short version:

What is the proper way to list/query files by suffix, "fullText contains 'ext', "fileExtension = 'ext'" or "title contains 'ext'"? These do not always return the same results; only one of them is documented (the first), and it's not consistent.

Long versions:

I've been developing Google Drive apps for years. Every now and then I have to change to my list queries to get the correct results. My application needs to find files with a certain suffix. Official documentation indicates that I need to use the "fullText contains 'ext'" syntax, but sometimes this fails to find some files. At one time I switched to the undocumented "fileExtension = 'ext'" syntax, but again after some time I found files that wouldn't show up and went back to fullText searches. However, again I've seen files not showing up with that search and tried using "title contains 'ext'" (or v3 "name contains 'ext'") which seems to work, but for how long? I don't like using undocumented queries which might just suddenly stop working.

I feel like I'm going in circles since I don't know why fullText fails (and only for some users, and when it does work I've seen the parents field come up empty sometimes...which doesn't happen with other queries) or why the title search works (not documented to search suffixes...and I'm pretty sure it didn't used to work). I might just perform all three searches, but this affects performance, and the "or" keyword with some combinations of those three searches returns no results at all.

My application has thousands of files, each with multiple revisions, in hundreds of folders and each folder is shared with dozens of users and those permissions are changing on a regular basis as people are added and removed from projects. There are hundreds of different owners of the individual files. I suspect this complexity and the time it takes to propagate permissions and file changes affects my queries, but doesn't explain why one search would work and another wouldn't or why the information returned on a file in one query would be different from the other. That is, even after several days the problem doesn't correct itself and often a file must be remove and re-uploaded for everyone to see it. I have experienced the slow updates to meta data for shared files resulting in mismatches between meta data, files, and search results, but I take all of that into account and still have queries which simply won't work properly.

Maybe I'm expecting too much from a free API? Overall I'm very happy with what i can do, but it can be very frustrating when it's not working and you *know* you're doing it right! :)

Comment: please read the guildines for posting

Comment: @johnny 5, I thought I had. Sorry. Please provide more specific feedback and I'll fix my question or remove it and start over. Google redirects users to this site to "Contact the team - Ask for help" so here I am...asking for help...hoping to contact the team, as it were.

Answer (score 0):

You can search or filter files with the '*files.list*' or '*children.list*' methods of the Drive API. These methods accept the 'q' parameter which is search query. 
For more information, see: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters

Comment: thanks for the reply. I suspect I have not stated my question clearly enough to get the proper response. I understand fairly well how to use the Google Drive API, but was trying to get clarity on how those three specific query variations were supposed to work and why they don't see to work as documented. If this type of question is not appropriate here I'll withdraw it and find another place to get feedback from Google. Thanks.